# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object in asp.net 1.1

Tags: asp.net

I am using aspnet framework 1.1 and i am getting error

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding) +126
System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +154

[HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]
System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +213
System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +50
System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod() +70
System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +128
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain() +63
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2490; ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2494

---

I tried adding

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="10000" />
```

But its still throwing the same error.

Can anyone suggest me any workaround for this?

Regards,
Murthy

Answer (score 0):

Check the request with Fiddler.

The error is:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]
```

So your form data is broken somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Adding that line to Web.Config works only for .NET 2.0 and above. For 1.1 you need to change registry settings, value of the key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\1.1.4322.0\MaxHttpCollectionKeys
```